# I can't display String from API to View

Tags: ios, swiftui

I tried to store the text in a variable of API
in the class
I do not want to transfer the entire model, I want to transfer the text as it is here

```
class Api : ObservableObject{

@Published var title : String = ""
@Published var details : String = ""

func getDataModelApi () {
    
    guard let url = URL(string: APIgetURL.demo) else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    let token = "38|xxxxx"
    
    request.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, responce, err in
        
        guard let data = data else { return }
        
        do {
            let dataModel = try JSONDecoder().decode([model].self, from: data)
            
            for i in dataModel {
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    
                    self.title = i.title
                    self.details = i.details
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("error: ", error)
        }
    }
    .resume()
}
}
```

In the title variable, the value was stored successfully, but the display in the view does not get anything

```
struct ContentView: View {

@StateObject var model3 = Api()

var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        Text(model3.title)
    }

    .onAppear() {
       
        Api().getDataModelApi()
    }
}
}
```

Here in getData, it shows the complete model and needs a link, which I want to access from getDataModelApi

```
@Published var models : [model] = []

func getData (url : String) {
    
    guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    let token = "38|xxx"
    
    request.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, responce, err in
        
        guard let data = data else { return }
        
        do {
            let dataModel = try JSONDecoder().decode([model].self, from: data)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.models = dataModel
                
            }
        } catch {
            print("error: ", error)
        }
    }
    .resume()
}
```

Comment: Did you try to validate whether you did successfully retrieve the data? try print("\\(self.title)") in your getDataModelApi() function to see what did you get.

Comment: Also, why you call Api().getDataModelApi() in onAppear()? I thought you should use model3.getDataModelApi() in your onAppear()

Comment: Note also, that doing this `for i in dataModel {...}` will set the Published var `title` and `details` **only** of the last `model` of your `dataModel` array. Take @tail advice and use `model3.getDataModelApi() ` in `onAppear`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using two different instances of `Api` and you throw away the second one in `onAppear`.

Replace

```
.onAppear() {
    Api().getDataModelApi()
}
```

With

```
.onAppear() {
    model3.getDataModelApi()
}
```

Comment: True, that worked, but there is something crazy. I did this for something else. I want to write the value of model3.title in onAppear, but it didn't work. Why isn't the value updated in onAppear?

Comment: **.onAppear() {
            model3.getDataModelApi()
            model2.getData(url: model3.title)
}**

Comment: what is `model2`? Do you use it like `model3`, such as `Text(model2.title)` or something similar? The problem you have is that `model3.getDataModelApi()` is an asynchronous function (look this up). You must "wait" until it has finished, before you can use its results, and in your case to pass into `model2.getData(url: model3.title)`. Look up asynchronous functions and completion handler.

Comment: I have added the one in the Model2 to the topic above

Comment: A whole week and I am trying to solve it. Please give me a guest to solve the problem of waiting for data

Comment: Because URLSession works asynchronously. A possible solution is async/await.

Comment: can you update your code and show us what code you are using, rather than bits and pieces. For example, where do you have `model2`, how do you declare it, what info do you display from it? Did you look up asynchronous functions?

Comment: I used it (complate: @escaping ([model])-> ()) And you already succeeded Thank you so much for your time